# Avoid showing logger entries in console

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have one "basic" logging configuration that logs to stdout in my project.

```
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

SERVER_FORMAT = "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s"
DATETIME_FORMAT = "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format=SERVER_FORMAT,
    datefmt=DATETIME_FORMAT,
    handlers=[stream_handler])
```

I have also another logger `user_logger` that should not print anything. Instead, it should store log entries in a variable.

```
user_logger = logging.getLogger('user_logger')
user_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

log_capture_string = io.StringIO()
log_capture_string_handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_capture_string)
log_capture_string_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

log_capture_string_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(USER_FORMAT))
user_logger.handlers = [log_capture_string_handler]
```

The problem is that when I call:

`user_logger.info('This should only be in "log_capture_string"')`

it prints it to the console.

Do you know how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `user_logger.propagate = False`. [logging.propagate docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate)

> If this evaluates to false, logging messages are not passed to the handlers of ancestor loggers.

So, your root logger will not send any data to stderr.

This example outputs nothing

```
import io
import logging

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

SERVER_FORMAT = "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s"
DATETIME_FORMAT = "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format=SERVER_FORMAT,
    datefmt=DATETIME_FORMAT,
    handlers=[stream_handler])

user_logger = logging.getLogger('user_logger')
user_logger.propagate = False
user_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

log_capture_string = io.StringIO()
log_capture_string_handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_capture_string)
log_capture_string_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

log_capture_string_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(SERVER_FORMAT))
user_logger.handlers = [log_capture_string_handler]

user_logger.info('This should only be in "log_capture_string"')
```